# SQLAlchemy How to load dates with timezone=UTC (dates stored without timezone)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model with a date column defined as :

```
created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now(), nullable=False)
```

The dates comme out with tz_info=None, which is correct, since the dates are stored
without timezone info.

If I print the date :

```
print(my_object.created_on.isoformat())
```

I get this format

```
2014-04-26T17:46:27.353936
```

I would like to have a UTC timezone indicator, such as :

```
2014-04-26T17:46:27.353936Z
```

Is there a way to define this behavior in the schema config ?

SQLAlchemy has, timezone=Boolean

sqlalchemy.types.DateTime(timezone=False)

since I want the storage to be without timezone.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want a custom data type, described here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#custom-types

Specifically, something like this:

```
import pytz  # from PyPI

class AwareDateTime(db.TypeDecorator):
    '''Results returned as aware datetimes, not naive ones.
    '''

    impl = db.DateTime

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return value.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

Then just make the column like this:

```
created_on = db.Column(AwareDateTime, default=db.func.now(), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend to use [Arrow type](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.arrow).

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy_utils import ArrowType
import arrow


class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.Unicode(255))
    created_at = sa.Column(ArrowType)



article = Article(created_at=arrow.utcnow())
```